# ¿how filter undefined elements into an array in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, ecmascript-6

I want to be able to pull the undefined elements out of the array, so that my table can correctly display the values. Currently I have this problem, where the following table shows the data corresponding to those tables, but it seems that the arrays occupy positions with the data that cannot be displayed, and I would like to remove them from the array:
**[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mc3oE.png)**

this is the code:

```
      team.playerHasTeams.map((player) => {
        playersInTeamData.push({
          idTeam: team.id,
          playerName: player.bookings.full_form_data.name,
          lastName: player.bookings.full_form_data.lastname,
          location: player.bookings.full_form_data.location,
          dateBirth: player.bookings.full_form_data.birth_date,
          gender: player.bookings.full_form_data.gender,
          position: player.bookings.full_form_data.position
        }) 
      })
      let formatedData = playersInTeamData.map((player, index) => {
        if (player.idTeam === team.id) {
          return {
            key: index,
            assingTeam: (
              <Form.Item>
                <Select placeholder="Assign">
                  {searchResponse.map((team, index) => (
                    <Select.Option key={index} value={team.id}>
                      {team.official_name}
                    </Select.Option>
                  ))}
                </Select>
              </Form.Item>
            ),
            playerName: player.playerName,
            lastName: player.lastName,
            location: player.location,
            dateBirth: player.dateBirth,
            gender: player.gender,
            position: player.position
          }
        }
      })
```

Comment: Check Array.prototype.filter method

Comment: It returns empty elements because you are using Array.map poorly.

Comment: You can use **filter** method of array.
This method is used to filter the array and return values on the basis of some condition.
**Note** that filter method always **returns a new Array**, and does not makes changes to the existing one.

    let newArray = Array.filter(v => v);

Use this and all the **undefined, null** values will be removed from the array.

Comment: @CertainPerformance That answer isn't helpful as this is an X-Y question.

Comment: yes, it worked very good, thank you @SiddharthAgrawal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use

```
Array.filter(cur => cur);
```

It will remove all falsy values from your array